# Can’t find a <p> tag to style

Tags: css

Hi how can I edit a `<p>` tag found on index. I have used the inspect in chrome but it’s not linked to any of the css files.. it has set the font style to 30px instead of 14px.

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

I have attached screenshot ...its dynamically generated. the

inherited from it.

Comment: It will either be in one of your theme's templates or in your post body HTML. Can you work out where it is in the page structure, e.g. a parent element with a class you can search for, and then look in the theme templates for that?

Comment: You can see the <p> is inside the woocommerce-MyAccount-content div and not the notices-wrapper, meaning it's generated by the woocommerce_account_content action which by default means [woocommerce_account_content()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.8.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L3065). What does it contain? Is there anything likely there that's generating it?

Comment: What do you see when you click on the "(index):231" in the style viewer? I guess that's an inline stylesheet in the page? Can you find where that's generated? Again I'd guess it's in your theme somewhere.